# Animating logo with SVG and CSS keyframes

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm using CSS keyframes and SVG to animate my company logo, which should be a fairly straight forward process but I must have missed something because as you can see in the JS Fiddle below it has a thin inside fill within the white line. I want the characters to be a single white line only.
I've set the fill to none and the font which the logo is based is outlined into one single path, so not sure what can be causing this?

https://jsfiddle.net/nzz970aL/1/

Markup

```
<div class="placeholder">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="35.6 317.2 863.3 110.8" enable-background="new 35.6 317.2 863.3 110.8" xml:space="preserve">
            <path class="logo" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="4" d="M86.8 349.2c0-12.2-9.7-21.9-21.9-21.9s-22.3 9.9-22.3 21.9c0 12.2 10.7 18.8 22.1 22.1 15.1 4.3 27.5 12.2 27.5 27.5 0 15.1-12.2 27.7-27.5 27.7s-27.5-12.6-27.5-27.7c0.2-1.6 1.2-2.5 2.9-2.5 1.4 0 2.7 0.8 2.7 2.3 -0.2 12.2 9.7 22.3 21.9 22.3s21.9-10.1 21.9-22.1c0-12.2-10.5-19.2-21.9-21.9 -14.5-3.7-27.5-12.2-27.5-27.7 0-14.9 12.4-27.5 27.7-27.5s27.3 12.4 27.3 27.5c-0.2 1.9-1.4 2.7-2.7 2.7C87.7 351.9 86.8 350.9 86.8 349.2L86.8 349.2zM227.3 422.3v0.8c0 1.7-1 2.7-2.7 2.7 -1.2 0-1.7-0.4-2.3-1.2l-46.5-91.9 -45 87.6h43.4c1.7 0 2.9 1 2.9 2.7s-1 2.7-2.7 2.7h-52.7l54.1-105.2L227.3 422.3zM281.7 328.1h-37.6c-1.7 0-2.5-1-2.5-2.7s1-2.7 2.7-2.7h77.9c1.7 0 2.7 1.2 2.7 2.7 0 1.7-1 2.7-2.7 2.7h-34.9v94.6c0 1.9-1 3.1-2.7 3.1s-2.7-1-2.7-2.7v-95H281.7zM361 325.2c0-1.7 1-2.7 2.7-2.7s2.7 1 2.7 2.7v57.2c0 20.7 17.4 38.2 38.2 38.2 21.1 0 38.2-17.2 38.2-38.2v-56.8c0-1.7 1-2.9 2.7-2.9 1.7 0 2.7 1 2.7 2.7v57.2c0 24-19.6 43.6-43.6 43.6S361 406.6 361 382.5L361 325.2 361 325.2zM490.3 322.7h35.5c19.8 0 35.3 15.7 35.3 35.3 0 17.6-12.6 32.2-29.3 34.9l27.9 28.1h-0.2c0.8 0.6 1.2 1.6 1.2 2.1 0 1.7-1 2.7-2.7 2.7 -1.2 0-1.6-0.2-2.1-1L524 393.2h-28.3v29.7c0 2.1-1 3.3-2.7 3.3s-2.7-1-2.7-2.7L490.3 322.7 490.3 322.7zM495.7 387.8h30c16.3 0 29.7-13.6 29.7-29.8s-13.4-29.8-29.7-29.8h-30L495.7 387.8 495.7 387.8zM701.7 422.3v0.8c0 1.7-1 2.7-2.7 2.7 -1.2 0-1.7-0.4-2.3-1.2l-46.3-91.9 -45 87.6h43.4c1.7 0 2.9 1 2.9 2.7s-1 2.7-2.7 2.7h-52.7l54.1-105.2L701.7 422.3zM756.2 328.1h-37.6c-1.7 0-2.5-1-2.5-2.7s1-2.7 2.7-2.7h77.9c1.7 0 2.7 1.2 2.7 2.7 0 1.7-1 2.7-2.7 2.7h-34.9v94.6c0 1.9-1 3.1-2.7 3.1 -1.7 0-2.7-1-2.7-2.7v-95H756.2zM840.9 376.1v44.2h53.7c1.7 0 2.9 1 2.9 2.7s-1 2.7-2.7 2.7h-59.5V322.7h59.1c1.9 0 3.1 1 3.1 2.7s-1 2.7-2.7 2.7h-53.9c0 7.4-0.2 14.1-0.2 21.3v21.1h8.7c2.1 0 3.1 1 3.1 2.7s-0.8 2.7-2.7 2.7h-8.9V376.1z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #000;
        }
        .placeholder {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 99;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
        svg {
            max-width: 480px;
        }
        .logo {
            stroke-dasharray:1000;
            stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
            -webkit-animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
            animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
        }
        @keyframes dash {
          from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
          }
          to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
        }
```

Comment: What were you expecting?  Your letters have a transparent fill and are placed on a black background. What were you expecting the fill of the letters to be, if not black?

Comment: Ok, so its the path that's the problem? I wasn't expecting any fill just a simple (white) line - will update my question.

Comment: Yes, your letters are defined by their outlines.  That is normal for fonts.  If you want each letter to be a single path, then they need to be (re-)drawn that way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Is there any easy way of achieving this rather than to redraw the characters manually?

Comment: Not really no.  Unless something like this is good enough for you: https://jsfiddle.net/nzz970aL/2/ (making the stroke thicker so the fill is not visible)

Comment: Thanks, tried that and I guess that will do for now just need to get it done.

Comment: Just mentioning that none of this works for me in Chrome btw, I just get a black screen.

Comment: Ok. I'll probably scrap the whole idea, heard more comments about it not behaving correctly.